# Query order by (product of two colums)

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL database there is a column 'date' (Y-m-d) and a column 'frequency (in months)'.
I want my to order my query (ORDER BY) by 'date' x 'frequency' (in months).
What can I do?

Comment: Is it possible to add the example with data?

Comment: $con = "SELECT
  i.number,
  i.name,
  i.lastday,
  i.frequency
 FROM
  planningi
 ORDER BY
  i.lastday x i.frequency  <------------ ?
  ";
  $res = mysqli_query( $link, $con );
  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $res ) ) :

Comment: I want to view your data.

Comment: one row (lastday) is 2018-01-01  frequency = 6. So I want to order by de new date: 2018-01-01 x 6 months = 2018-07-01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Sql query will be like that: (I am assuming your `frequency` will contain always number of month.

```
 $con = "SELECT i.number, i.name, i.lastday, i.frequency FROM planningi ORDER BY DATE_ADD(i.lastday, INTERVAL i.frequency month) asc
```

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation